# how to implement HSTS for magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php, seo

How to implement HSTS in magento?

I have just moved from http to https, and I read that HSTS should be implemented to reduce latency and improve security, so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following to your .htaccess file to enable it:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=84600; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: how to add it for particular store?

Answer (score 2):

Ikonoshirt_StrictTransportSecurity is a free extension which implements HSTS in Magento. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ikonoshirt/StrictTransportSecurity). Just install it and you are done.

Comment: If you have any problem with my extension, tell me and I'll fix. Afaik is this extension only in use on my site :-)